# parentNode.removeChild not removing last element. But why?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a javascript code where I can clone an element, but also want to delete one on click. Cloning works, but I can't remove one.

I have the following elements.

```
<input list="accountsdeb" name="deblist[1]" id="deblist" autocomplete="off">
<input list="accountsdeb" name="deblist[2]" id="deblist" autocomplete="off">
```

And now I want to remove the last one on click (last = highest number).

```
function remove1() {
  var dbl = document.querySelectorAll('#deblist').length;
  var dbla = dbl;
  var elem = document.getElementsByName("deblist["+dbla+"]");
  alert(dbla);
  //var last = debelelast - 1;
  elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
```

As an orientation I used to have a look on an example from W3S and Stack. I have also seen that this works:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myDiv");
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

But this is random and as you can see I have tried to include this in my code.
The error I get is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of undefined
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.remove1 (index.php:179)

Where's the problem in my code, where is my thinking wrong?

Comment: Please show relevant markup including `myDiv`.

Comment: in HTML, id must be **unique**, if you reuse one, only the first element in the DOM order will be selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues in the piece of code you provided,

1. `deblist` is used as id for 2 elements which is not advisable and due to this `document.querySelectorAll('#deblist').length` returns 2 (I am not sure if you intending to do so)
2. `document.getElementsByName()` (check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)) will return a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which needs to be iterated in order to access any of the returned elements. So here you need to select the child element by giving its index. In your case `elem` will have one element for the matched name `deblist[2]` and hence you need to access it like `elem[0]` for selecting its parent and deleting its child.

So the updated the code would be,

```
var dbl = document.querySelectorAll('#deblist').length;
var dbla = dbl;
// console.log('dbla', dbla);
var elem = document.getElementsByName("deblist["+dbla+"]");
// console.log('elem 0', elem[0]);
// console.log('elem parentNode', elem[0].parentNode);
//var last = debelelast - 1;
elem[0].parentNode.removeChild(elem[0]);
```

Check the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b45kfkem/)

Comment: Hey,
the intention in point 1 is indeed to count how many elements exist.

I have tried your fiddle and works so far. In my case I'd execute the code above on click. I tried and this didn't work in the fiddle. Could there be a correlation?

However, I'll take a deeper look and may have to restructure. So this may need some.

Comment: I mean I made a change to the fiddle by adding a button with onclick and it didn't work. :-)

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b45kfkem/1/). this is working even in onclick

Comment: Worked well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the inputs are part of a group they could share a name property or such, and the use of jQuery could help you do something like...

```
$("input[name='group1']").last().parent().remove()
```

Or if not part of a group then just....

```
$("input").last().parent().remove()
```